# Get Percentage From The Sum Of Multiple Queries

Tags: sql

I am trying to get a percentage from the total gross divided by the concessions (credits and discounts). The first query gives me all the gross income, the next two queries give me the concessions. These two queries are almost the same with the exception of the criterias. I can't figure out how to get the percentage. I need to show the Gross Potential Rate, Effective Rate After Concessions and Percentage of Difference which is about 2%. Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
'Gross Potential Rate' AS Status,
sum(Units.dcPushRate) as DollarAmt
from Units 
inner join UnitTypes with (nolock) on UnitTypes.UnitTypeID = Units.UnitTypeID
where Units.SiteID = '30250' AND Units.dDeleted IS NULL AND sUnitName <> 'POS$' and units.sUnitName LIKE 'H%'
UNION ALL 
Select 'Effective Rate After Concessions' as Status, SUM(c) FROM
(
select sum(charges.dcPrice) * -1 as c from Charges 
inner join ledgers with (nolock) on charges.ledgerid = ledgers.ledgerid 
inner join units with (nolock) on units.unitid = ledgers.unitid 
where charges.siteid ='30250' and units.sUnitName LIKE 'H%' and charges.dchgstrt BETWEEN @dStart  AND @dEnd and charges.dcstdprice = charges.dcPrice and charges.concessionid IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
select sum(charges.dcPrice) * -1 as c from Charges 
inner join ledgers with (nolock) on charges.ledgerid = ledgers.ledgerid 
inner join units with (nolock) on units.unitid = ledgers.unitid 
where charges.siteid ='30250' and units.sUnitName LIKE 'H%' and charges.dchgstrt BETWEEN @dStart  AND @dEnd and charges.dcstdprice ='0.00'
UNION ALL 
select 
sum(Units.dcPushRate) as DollarAmt
from Units 
inner join UnitTypes with (nolock) on UnitTypes.UnitTypeID = Units.UnitTypeID
where Units.SiteID = '30250' AND Units.dDeleted IS NULL AND sUnitName <> 'POS$' and units.sUnitName LIKE 'H%'
) a
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately this question is hard to digest as it isn't a http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Could you provide perhaps a small sample of your current data and the results you have generated thus far so that the community can better understand your query? Can you also clarify how you would calculate "Percentage of Difference"?

Comment: Yes Zorgarath. Here's the end result from these queries:
GROSS POTENTIAL RATE 3,837.50 
EFFECTIVE RATE AFTER CONCESSIONS 3,741.50 

I need help in figuring out how to do this: (GROSS POTENTIAL RATE - EFFECTIVE RATE AFTER CONCESSIONS) / GROSS POTENTIAL RATE *100 = Percent

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to solve everything in SQL. You will have to use the same queries again in a calculation to work out the percentage values.

You might be better off leaving the percentage calculation to your presentation layer as it will have the necessary values in a simpler form.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'presentation layer'. I need this to be in the form of a query. I'm looking for a solution where I can accomplish these things with queries.